# не выводит новый массив arr1, берет только первое значения матрицы и четыре раза его записывает в новый массив

Tags: c++

```
void f2(int** arr, int *arr1, int max ,int n, int m, int& k, int& l){
if (k > l)
{
    max = arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (max > arr[i][j])
            {
                max = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        arr1[i] = max;
        cout << arr1[i] << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "net";
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваше условие ищет минимум. Приведите пример вызова.

Comment: f2(A, B, n, m, max, l, k);

Comment: даже если оно ищет минимум, то неправильно

Comment: минимальный **рабочий** пример + **ожидаемый** результат

Comment: Тут скорее важен тот пример данных, на которых вы не получаете ожидаемый результат.

Comment: я длбавил вывод

Comment: 79 это кол-во отрицательных и положительных элементов без пробела

Comment: Вы привели пример: `f2(A, B, n, m, max, l, k);`. В нём у вас не совпадает порядок аргументов с тем, что находится у вас в функции. Потому и нужно, чтобы вы привели минимальный рабочий пример т.к. ошибка может быть скрыта в других частях кода.

Comment: короче перепутаны аргументы `n`<-> `m`<-> `max`

Comment: теперь программа выводит все отрицательные максимальные элементы, причем так, что если в первой строке самый большой ,то весь массив им заполнится (то есть выведет одно значение 4 раза)

Comment: Вы всё ещё не объяснили что программа должна выводить. Если максимальное значение в каждом ряду, то `max = arr[0][0];` стоит перенести в первый цикл как `max = arr[i][0];` (И поправить условие сравнения).

Comment: программа должна выводить максимальное значение элемента в каждой строке и записывать его в новый массив

Comment: needKVAS спасибо большое

Comment: а почему он выводит значения с минусом, если я поставил условие, что max>0

Comment: В `f2` я этого условия не вижу

Comment: я добавил это условие

Comment: Стоит тогда задать новый вопрос. Сложно сказать вслепую.

Answer (score 1):

```
void f2(int** arr, int *arr1, int n, int m)
{
    int max;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        max = arr[i][0]; // max должен переприсваиваться в каждой строке, 
                         // чтобы искать максимум в строке, а не во всей матрице
        for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
            if (max < arr[i][j]) // условие должно быть < , иначе ищется минимум
                max = arr[i][j];

        arr1[i] = max;
        cout << arr1[i] << endl;
    }
}
```